# Android: NoClassDefFoundError using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, noclassdeffounderror

I´m trying to use the ViewPager concept first and now I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.unserekinder.Bilderbuch
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.example.unserekinder.Ereignisse.onOptionsItemSelected(Ereignisse.java:176)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-06 10:50:47.293: E/AndroidRuntime(1295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here´s my code:

```
public class Bilderbuch extends FragmentActivity {
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bilderbuch);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

        return fList;
    }

    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }
}


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

    public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message){
        MyFragment f  = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_fragment, container, false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        messageTextView.setText(message);

    return v;
    }
```

Here is the layout file of `Bilderbuch`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

And here the one of `MyFragment`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make project right click properties-> Java BuildPath select Library and add jar android-support-v4.jar  the follow these step.

Go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path than select Order and export tab. Set android-support-v4.jar library checked and up it into top of the list. And clean and rebuild..It works for most of the cases

Comment: I have same issue before and i tried same it work fine so tried the same i hope it will work for you also